# How to stack bar graph with continuos numbers as a discrete numbers using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to graph the quality of a production process.

For this question lets say the data.frame is described as:

```
df2 <- data.frame(size = c("XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL"),
                    ok = c(1, 3, 4, 2, 1),
                 notok = c(0, 1, 1, 2, 0))      

size ok notok
 XS  1     0
  S  3     1
  M  4     1
  L  2     2
 XL  1     0
```

Now I want to show hoy many of the total products produced were ok. So I try:

```
ggplot(df2, aes(x=size, y=(ok+notok), fill=ok)) +
    geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

However, the result I got is a a graph showing the ok variable as if "ok" was a scale.

I also tried using     fill=factor(ok) but the result wasn't what I was expecting.

How can I get a graph that shows how many of the total were ok in each bin?

Something like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ggplot` tends to work best if data are in long, rather than wide form. To convert between the two, you can make use of the excellent `reshape` package. Try this:

```
require(reshape)
df3 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "size")
```

Your data are now in long format as shown below, and can be more easily plotted:

```
   size variable value
1    XS       ok     1
2     S       ok     3
3     M       ok     4
4     L       ok     2
5    XL       ok     1
6    XS    notok     0
7     S    notok     1
8     M    notok     1
9     L    notok     2
10   XL    notok     0


ggplot(df3, aes(x = size, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", aes(fill = variable))
```

...Which produces the following graph:

[image]